# Angular Bootstrap UI Datepicker with custom directive $parser causes error: Not a valid date ng model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to use the angularjs bootstrap ui datepicker directive on an input element that also has another directive that adds a $parser to the model.  I get an error because the model object is not a Date object (because the parser causes the mdoel object to be an object with property named, "customValue".

The actual error when I select a date is, "Datepicker directive: "ng-model" value must be a Date object, a number of milliseconds since 01.01.1970 or a string representing an RFC2822 or ISO 8601 date."

I have tried setting the priority on the customFormProp directive, as well as using $parsers.unshift (instead of push), but none seemed to work.

How do I get the angular bootstrap ui datepicker to work correctly on an element that has a directive that sets the model object to a value other than date?

```
angular.module('app').directive('customFormPropp', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
            ngModel.$parsers.push(function toModel(value) {
                return {customValue: value};
            });

            ngModel.$formatters.push(function toView(input) {
                return input.value;
            });
        }
    };
}]);

<p class="input-group">
     <input name="endInterval" type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{'MM/dd/yy'}}" ng-model="vm.form.endInterval" custom-form-prop="endInterval" is-open="vm.dates.endOpened" />
         <span class="input-group-btn">
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="vm.toggleOpenDatePicker($event, 'endOpened')"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
         </span>
</p>
```

Comment: why can't you  pass date to model? And what are you trying to pass to it?

Comment: The customFormProp directive sets the model to be { customValue: <dateobj>}.  The angular bootstrap datepicker ui directive tries to use the modelValue to create a Date obj with: new Date( ngModelCtrl.$modelValue ).  $modelValue is { customValue: <dateobj> } though so it fails.

Comment: remove the `custom-form-prop` from input. Still not clear what's going on...a demo would help

Comment: If I remove the custom-form-prop from the input it works as expected, but I would like to keep this directive because other code expects all the model values be objects with a property called 'customValue'.  I can try and put this code into a demo to see if it makes it easier to explain.

Comment: I thought it might be a common use case where a single input element has multiple directives on it, and each directive assumes the model value is in a certain format.

Comment: I'm not seeing use case for different formats on same property...or how they wouldn't conflict